# Create new client for every operation to firestore?

Tags: firebase, go, google-cloud-firestore

I see examples like these in firestore Go Docs. Should we have to create a client like below for every operation to firestore or can we create a client during application startup and use the same client to perform an operation? Please let me know.

```
ctx := context.Background()
client, err := firestore.NewClient(ctx, "project-id")
if err != nil {
    // TODO: Handle error.
}
defer client.Close()

type State struct {
    Capital    string  `firestore:"capital"`
    Population float64 `firestore:"pop"` // in millions
}

wr, err := client.Doc("States/Colorado").Create(ctx, State{
    Capital:    "Denver",
    Population: 5.5,
})
if err != nil {
    // TODO: Handle error.
}
fmt.Println(wr.UpdateTime)
```

Comment: Such clients tend to be safe for sequential use, and often safe for concurrent use. You'll need to either dig through the docs, or try it out to check.

Comment: You can use the same client that was created during the startup to perform an operation. Here's a [similar Stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52752037).

Comment: Got it. Thanks for pointing me to post.

Answer (score 0):

No.Create the client once and re-use the same client. More details on this post - [Should a Firestore client be created per a request with Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52752037/should-a-firestore-client-be-created-per-a-request-with-google-app-engine)